# LUKS header modified?

Tags: security, password, luks, password-store

When a LUKS password is sent to the LUKS header for decryption, can it be stolen by a hacker who modified the LUKS header? Suppose my boot partition is healthy.

Answer (score 2):

LUKS header contains no executable code, only one or more encrypted copies of the master key of the LUKS partition. Each configured passphrase/keyfile/other access method will decrypt a copy of the master key, which is needed to access the encrypted disk. The LUKS password is not "sent to LUKS header for decryption": instead, the `cryptsetup luksOpen` command *reads* the LUKS header, then decrypts it in memory using the password.

If a hacker has successfully modified the LUKS header, it pretty much indicates the hacker (or a hacking tool) already knew the LUKS password, as it is needed to successfully modify the LUKS header without corrupting it.

A possible scenario might be a hacker adding replacing the regular `cryptsetup` command in the initramfs file of your root partition with a modified one: the modified `cryptsetup` would request your LUKS password just like a normal one, but then, in addition to unlocking the disk, would re-encrypt the master key of the LUKS partition with another password that is known to the attacker, and store it in one of the free slots in the LUKS header. Alternatively, it could just store the unencrypted master key in some hidden location outside the encrypted LUKS partition. Then the modified `cryptsetup` could replace the modified initramfs file on your boot partition with the original one, making it hard to detect what has really happened.

`cryptsetup luksDump` can be used to view the contents of the LUKS header in human-readable form. If you see more key slots in use than expected, you can use `cryptsetup luksKillSlot` to disable the unauthorized key slots without knowing the password associated with them. Be careful with this command: it is possible to lock yourself out of the encrypted disk if you make mistakes with this command.

Comment: My older password is very simple for a hacker, suppose my password and LUKS header get stolen , also I didn't cryptsetup-reencrypt my LUKS after password changing (change to a new one), I want to know is that the newer password used for older LUKS is safe for reuse in the new LUKS header (I'm going to re-create a new header with cryptsetup-reencrypt)?

Comment: As far as I know, the new password should be safe. But the hacker could get the master key of the LUKS partition from the stolen things, and until you run `cryptsetup-reencrypt` to successful completion, the hacker could easily decrypt your disk if s/he can gain access to it.

Comment: ok, You'v help me a lot, especially your first reply, open my mind on how smart a hacker and linuxer is, second one is what I need. Thank you for your patient!